# Drag & Drop with ItemsControl in Metro (C#/XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, drag-and-drop, microsoft-metro

I have an app where I'm having a usercontrol consisting of an ItemsControl with squares (represented by a border and underlying controls).
Think of it like a chessboard.

Since my ItemTemplate consists of a border it doesn't have native support for drag & drop like the GridView or the ListView. I tried using both GridView and ListView for my squares Before but the GUI became too sluggish so I switched to a simple border which made it alot faster.

By hooking up Manipulation events I've still managed to get a drag behavior for my border and its content (at least when it comes to the GUI).
However when I try to drag a square (border) to another square I can't seem to get the drop event to fire. I need to know which the target square is.

I understand that since I'm doing my drag&drop functionality myself I need to do something to hook into the border's drop event, but what?

I've also tried to subscribe to the border events PointerEntered, PointerMoved etc. to find out which square the pointer is over and when the button is released i would know which the target square is. This only seem to work in two directions though (right and down), the Pointer events doesn't seem to fire when moved left or up, strange. I've read somwhere that the items (squares) have different ZIndex and this could affect the firing of events.

I've struggled with this for hours now and would really appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you looked into using DragEnter/DragOver/DragLeave and Drop events?

Answer (score 0):

Create an attached property and hook it up to the parent control outside the Border, place the native drag and drop to the TargetType of the ItemTemplate.

Hook it up to PreviewMouseUp and PreviewMouseDown Event.

More of this are found here [WPF Tutorial Drag and Drop](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include a `Thumb` object on top of whatever you want to drag & drop. The `Thumb` object will fire the required events and you can handle whatever behavior you want from these events (you might want to move the underlying object on the canvas to simulate dragging the underlying object for example).

You can have a look at [the MSDN page of Thumb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.thumb) to get you started.

Then when you have `Thumb` notification, you get a hold of your underlying in whatever way suits you, and you call `Canvas.SetLeft/Top (object, my new coordinates)`. Usually, your new coordinates will be something like `Canvas.GetLeft/Top(object) + args.Horizontal/VerticalChange`.

As you figured out, you have to use a `Canvas` and place the objects by yourself instead of using a `Grid` or a `ListView`.